# How do we apply css properties in material ui elements?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I just have started using [material ui](https://material-ui.com), and I don't understand how the spacing properties work. I'm checking how to use the "spacing" feature for some elements, but to be honest it seems that only work for "Box" components, but not for things like "Buttons".

According to [material ui spacing section](https://material-ui.com/system/spacing/) if we want to add margin or padding we can use `m` or `p` but if you try to use those properties as part of a `Button` component, it does not work:

```
<Button variant="contained" color="primary" mt={2}>
  Primary
</Button>
```

As you can see, I'm using `mt` (margin-top property) and based on what the docs says, that should be apply: `margin-top: 8px` but it does not set anything...

So, my question here is, *what are the elements where we can use the spacing properties in material ui? What am I doing wrong in my example?*

Comment: Are you using themeprovider for your application as a HOC? Also Button doesn't take any 'mt' prop ==> https://material-ui.com/api/button/

Comment: These theme properties can be applied only if you wrap your components with ThemeProvider and configure your theme to add these spacing and color properties.
Otherwise to add custom style to material ui components you can override them using makeStyles or withStyles.

Comment: nope, I'm not using theme provider, but do I really need it? For other components like "Box" you just set "m" or "p" attributes and that's it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to wrap your Button inside a Box component to apply spacing properties like this

```
<Box mt={2} color="primary" clone>
<Button variant="contained">
  Primary
</Button>
</Box>
```

Because Button component don't receive these spacing properties by default.

Comment: Button will not respond to these 'mt' props. You need to use spread syntax inorder to acheive that. Box provided props render syntax. That'll be helpful.